# Elastic search get one record per hour

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate-functions

I want to get only one record per hours in a date range. For Example, If I want to get the data's between the days (28-08-2018 - 15-09-2018) there are almost 10000 records, but I want to filter the result to show only one record per hour, So I am using **aggregation** with **date_histogram**, and I can see only one record per hour

Query :

```
{ 
    "size" : 0,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
                    {
              "range": {
                "createdtime": {
                  "gte": "1535201500000",
                  "lte": "1536756706000",
                  "boost": 2.0
                }
              }
            },

            {
              "match": {
                "gen": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "Mid": 350404
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },

    "aggregations" : {
        "runtime" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "createdtime",
                "interval" : "1H",
                "min_doc_count": 1
            },"aggs": {
                "tops": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "size": 1
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

Here the problem is I want to use pagination to show these results as I know there is no way to use size and from on aggregation query as of now, I want to know is there any other way to get only one records in an hour

Comment: If you really need to have pagination, It means that you have large amount of buckets in your result. In this case you can consider normalizing data, like splitting into hour based indexes, then you can try pagination. Otherwise just implement your own pagination logic.

Comment: @GkhnSr for the given example dates there is less number of records, but there is a possibility to get more data when chose the date difference in months, years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are grouping docs by hour, then for every interval you already know how many results are going to be.

For the interval you provided (28-08-2018 - 15-09-2018), there's 432 hours in between, so you know that there's going to be 432 results. Now, lets say you want to show 8 results per page, that means there's going to be 54 pages, where every page is going to contain results from 8 hour window:

1st page is 28-08-2018 **00:00:00** (1535410800000) - 28-08-2018 **08:00:00** (1535410800000 + 8 * 3600000)
so your aggregation request for the first page should look like:

```
...
  "range": {
    "createdtime": {
      "gte": "1535410800000",
      "lt": "1535439600000",
      "boost": 2.0
    }
  }
...
```

2nd page is 28-08-2018 **08:00:00** (1535410800000 + 8 * 3600000) - 28-08-2018 **16:00:00** (1535410800000 + 16 * 3600000)

```
...
  "range": {
    "createdtime": {
      "gte": "1535439600000",
      "lt": "1535468400000",
      "boost": 2.0
    }
  }
...
```

and so on, you just narrow down your aggregation based on *createdtime* and that will return results for particular page.